# neovim lsp diagnostic get_count deprecated but unused

Tags: neovim

I'm using nvim v0.7.0-dev, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
And I see the following error:

```
vim.lsp.diagnostic.get_count is deprecated. See :h deprecated
```

But I'm not using 'get_count', so, I can't change it, or remove or whatever. Why I see this error? and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there are some plugins that use `vim.lsp.diagnostic.get_count` and haven't upgraded yet. So you can temporarily disable these plugins or open new issue or find another similar plugins